# how to find the position of an element that contains a certain character

Tags: java, methods, chaining

So I have a list that stores names with a first and a family name. (this list is called regst)
And I already have some methods that separates the first name and last name and also a set and get method.

I have to execute a code that returns a string that represent each name in my regst list that has a first name containing either of the characters "a" or "e". Also that gets these names and outputs the first letter of first and family name.

So far I created this for loop!
My problem is how to select the names that contains these characters and returns a string where it get the first letter of the first name and family name?
Generally: how to find the position of an element that contains a certain character?

```java
for (int i = 0; i < regst.size(); i++) {            
    if (regst.getName(i).getFirstName().contains("a") || regst.getName(i).getFirstName().contains("e")) {
        System.out.println("All the first names that contains the characters a or e: "
                 + regst.getName(i).getFirstName().contains("a") 
                 + regst.getName(i).getFirstName().contains("e"));
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear from your description which structure does list contain? Is it some kind of Person class with firstName and lastName? Or what? If you iterate through regst list, then regst.getName(i).getFirstName() does not make any sense. Please describe what`s in list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don`t need to implement any iteration logic as ArrayList already has it.
Just get a list from register

```
List<Name> list = register.getList(); // you need a getter for this
```

Then just iterate through list and return list of needed names:

```
public List<Name> findNames(List<Name> list) {
    List<Name> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Name name : list) {
        if (name.getFirstName().contains("a") || name.getFirstName().contains("e")) {
            result.add(name);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or using Stream API:

```
public static List<Name> findNames(List<Name> list) {
return list.stream()
    .filter(name -> name.getFirstName().contains("a") || name.getFirstName().contains("e"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If you need to get first letter of that names, you can implement such method in Name class:

```
public String getInitials() {
    return firstName.charAt(0) + "." + familyName.charAt(0) + ".";
}
```